# Representing Conway's Game of Life

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix, grids

I'm writing an article about Conway's Game of Life, and I'm using the Springer LNCS template.

In my article, I must sometimes show some game of life patterns, for example the following:

[image: example_of_pattern]

To generate such pattern, I used the Tikz package. The code (without other formatting commands) is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[black] (1,4) rectangle (3,6);
  \fill[black] (11,3) rectangle (12,6);
  \fill[black] (12,2) rectangle (13,3);
  \fill[black] (12,6) rectangle (13,7);
  \fill[black] (13,1) rectangle (15,2);
  \fill[black] (13,7) rectangle (15,8);
  \fill[black] (15,4) rectangle (16,5);
  \fill[black] (16,2) rectangle (17,3);
  \fill[black] (16,6) rectangle (17,7);
  \fill[black] (17,3) rectangle (18,6);
  \fill[black] (18,4) rectangle (19,5);
  \fill[black] (21,5) rectangle (23,8);
  \fill[black] (23,4) rectangle (24,5);
  \fill[black] (23,8) rectangle (24,9);
  \fill[black] (25,3) rectangle (26,5);
  \fill[black] (25,8) rectangle (26,10);
  \fill[black] (35,6) rectangle (37,8);
  \draw[step=1cm,gray,thick] (0,0) grid (38,11);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see, this is pretty bad, expecially as I must now produce dozen of such patterns, and manually specifying the coordinates of every black cells is... well, not viable.

**The question is**: is there a way to achieve the same result as above, but using (for example) a *matrix-style* input?

What I mean is something like:

```
\sort-of-matrix-command {
    W & W & W & W & W & B \\
    W & B & W & W & W & W \\
    B & W & B & B & W & W \\
    W & W & B & B & B & W \\
    B & B & W & W & W & W \\
    W & W & W & W & W & W \\
}
```

where "W" or "B" stand for white cell and black cell respectively.

If it is not possible, any other way which is faster than the one I'm currently using is well accepted.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But for your picture, your matrix would be 37x10.  Wouldn't it be easier to define a macro so that `\square{1}{4}` becomes the first line in your code?

Comment: something like [pixel art in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157080/can-tikz-create-pixel-art-images) ?

Comment: easy in lualatex

Comment: Brilliant, thank you all! I honestly didn't even think about pixel-art.. thanks.

Comment: Here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145319/programming-conways-game-of-life-in-latex you have an animated version.

Comment: @marsupilam Real programmes do it in vanilla TeX. :-)

Comment: @marsupilam whatever

Comment: @JPi It is for a journal. What real programmers do is irrelevant.

Comment: Wasn't my comment.  Journal requirements vary a lot, even for the same publisher.